# como conectar com o couchdb no codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, couchdb

alguém sabe como conectar com o CouchDB usando o codeigniter?

Já tentamos muitos tutoriais, adicionamos as bibliotecas necessárias, mais não conseguimos sucesso. Por favor nos ajudem.

Comment: Coloca o link do tutorial, o código que você tentou e o erro, ta complicado esse CouchDB.

Comment: ta complicado sim,  o link é esse (https://github.com/dready92/PHP-on-Couch/) e os erros "require_once(couch.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
require_once(): Failed opening required 'couch.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')"

Comment: vc consegue rodar o couchdb fora do php? sabe se ele funciona direito?

Comment: o couchdb esta funcionando corretamente fora do php, o problema esta em conectar com o banco, não conseguimos ainda

Answer (score 1):

Estou finalizando aqui, obrigado, depois de muito esforço conseguimos conexão, é somente carregar a biblioteca no autoload. e começar a usar os metodos.

```
//no autoload.php
$autoload['libraries'] = array('couchdb');

//criar uma database
$dsn ='http://127.0.0.1:5984/';

$couch = new couchClient($dsn, 'testecouch'); // See if we can make a connection
$resp =  $couch->createDatabase();
```

a biblioteca esta funcionando perfeitamente.